# AD Authentication with principalattribute id is not working

Tags: ldap

I am using apereo cas LDAPAuthentication handler for authenticating users in active directory.

If I give cn then login is working fine but if I use samAccountName then it throw credentials not correct error.  I verified apereo logs and the resolved dn takes samaccountname instead of cn so it is failing.

My assumption is if we use principal attribute id as samaccountName then it will search for samAccountName and get the entry then take the cn to construct the dn then it will login.

In my case, it directly uses sam account name in dn so it is failing.

Can anyone help me with pointers.

```
2024-01-18 16:34:21,480 TRACE [org.ldaptive.PooledConnectionFactory] - <returned active connection: org.ldaptive.pool.AbstractConnectionPool$DefaultPooledConnectionP
2024-01-18 16:34:21,480 INFO [org.ldaptive.auth.Authenticator] - <Authentication failed for dn: CN=bilbo,OU=ouUsers,DC=Middle,DC=Earth>  

Here bilbo is actually samAccountName not cn.  but it takes as cn

2024-01-18 16:34:21,481 DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationManager] - <Authentication handler [gdrory-ldap-ad] FailedLoginException for [Usern
2024-01-18 16:34:21,481 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationManager] - <Authentication has failed. Credentials may be incorrect or CAS cannot f
2024-01-18 16:34:21,482 TRACE [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationManager] - <null>                                                                  
javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: null                                                                                           
        at org.apereo.cas.authentication.support.DefaultLdapAccountStateHandler.<init>(DefaultLdapAccountStateHandler.java:73) ~[cas-server-support-ldap-core-6.6.10.
        at org.apereo.cas.util.LdapUtils.createLdapPasswordPolicyConfiguration(LdapUtils.java:1077) ~[classes!/:6.6.10]             
        at org.apereo.cas.util.LdapUtils.createL



Base Dn : OU=ouUsers,DC=Middle,DC=Earth

User Filter : sAMAccountName={user}

Dn Format : CN=%s,OU=ouUsers,DC=Middle,DC=Earth

Principal Attribute Id : sAMAccountName

Policy BaseDn : OU=ouGroups,DC=Middle,DC=Earth

Policy Map Attribute : member=CN={user},OU=ouUsers,DC=Middle,DC=Earth

Policy Id : sAMAccountName
```

Comment: What happens if you _remove_ the "DN format" setting?